# Durandal does not compose footer view after main content was composed

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, durandal

I have a durandal shell view like this:

```
<div id="global">
<!-- ko compose: {view: 'nav'} -->
<!-- /ko-->
<div id="main" class="container">
    <!--ko compose: {model: router.activeItem, 
        afterCompose: router.afterCompose,
        transition: 'entrance'} -->
    <!-- /ko-->
</div>
<div id="push"></div>
 </div>
  <!-- ko compose: {view: 'footer'} -->
  <!-- /ko-->
```

'nav' and 'footer' are separate html views. When I run the site it works fine except that the footer html is never shown. However, when I put it like this the footer is being displayed (Although the page layout is wrong of course):

```
<div id="global">
<!-- ko compose: {view: 'nav'} -->
<!-- /ko-->
<!-- ko compose: {view: 'footer'} -->
 <!-- /ko-->
<div id="main" class="container">
    <!--ko compose: {model: router.activeItem, 
        afterCompose: router.afterCompose,
        transition: 'entrance'} -->
    <!-- /ko-->
</div>
<div id="push"></div>

 </div>
```

When I paste the html code of the footer directly into the shell it works as well of course.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Durandal views should have one root element http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Creating-A-View.

> The view has exactly one root element. Durandal requires this. If
>   comments are found at the root, they will be removed. In the case
>   where more than one root element is found, they will be wrapped in a
>   div.

The compose footer directive is a comment outside of `global` and therefore will be removed. Moving it inside `#global' should do the trick.

```
<div id="global">
<!-- ko compose: {view: 'nav'} -->
<!-- /ko-->
<div id="main" class="container">
    <!--ko compose: {model: router.activeItem, 
        afterCompose: router.afterCompose,
        transition: 'entrance'} -->
    <!-- /ko-->
</div>
<div id="push"></div>
<!-- ko compose: {view: 'footer'} -->
  <!-- /ko--> 
</div>
```

As an alternative you could wrap everything into another div element to fulfill the single root element without comment rule.

```
<div>
<div id="global">
<!-- ko compose: {view: 'nav'} -->
<!-- /ko-->
<div id="main" class="container">
    <!--ko compose: {model: router.activeItem, 
        afterCompose: router.afterCompose,
        transition: 'entrance'} -->
    <!-- /ko-->
</div>
<div id="push"></div>
 </div>
  <!-- ko compose: {view: 'footer'} -->
  <!-- /ko-->
</div>
```

Comment: RTFM I guess :) Thanks, I went with the second option

Comment: @fhoetzing - don't sweat it. :) something like that can easily be overlooked in a new framework such as Durandal

Comment: So it looks like you're adding the to `shell.html`... Is it possible to add it to the file that contains `shell.html`? E.G: `<body> ... <div id="applicationHost">...</div> <!-- THIS HERE --><div><div data-bind="compose: 'partials/globalNav.html'"></div></div> ... </body>`.  The reason I'm asking is cause I thought I could use `compose` simply as an include anywhere (just like ng-include for Angular).